# Officer vs. Staff vs. Personnel

Tags: differences

What is difference in usage between "Officer", "Staff" and "Personnel"?

For example, if I want to say about people who work for Google should I say
"Google's staff", "Google's Officer" or "Google's Personnel".

Comment: I think it depends on the context - of which we know nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of these terms varies from organisation to organisation, although 'personnel' is the most general.

In many organisations 'staff' are people in permanent, monthly paid, contracted, usually supervisory, clerical or technical positions but any other workers might be referred to as 'manual grades' or even 'casual employees' with fewer rights and benefits. There may even be agency workers who are not paid directly by the company. However it would usually be correct to refer to them all as 'personnel', even if they could not all be called 'employees' and certainly not 'staff' if the organisation used a tight definition of that term.

'Officer' is even more complicated, and again is dependent on the definition used by the employing organisation. Military officers are a very tightly defined group of people within the armed forces and certainly do not include the lowest ranks. Police officers are fully established police people of all ranks but do not include civilian staff such as clerical workers, technicians and cleaners. Local government officers, at least in the UK, tend to be people with clerical, supervisory and technical roles and do not include teachers or, usually, craftspeople or cleaners.

It would, however, be correct in most cases to refer to 'police personnel' or 'local government personnel' to refer to all people working in those areas regardless of their position, 'miltary personnel' has a tighter definition excluding civilians.

In addition there are organisations which refer to the people who work there by different terms. John Lewis stores in the UK, which is cooperatively owned, calls them 'partners', the Disney theme parks call them 'cast' and many companies refer to them as 'colleagues'. I have no idea what Google call theirs.

The safest bet for a general term is 'personnel' but don't expect it to be universally accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In the military an officer normally refers to a commissioned officer, that's to say a person of relatively senior rank in a position of authority. Commissioned officers originally received their commission (their appointment) from the monarch. Now they receive them from the state.

The lower ranks are referred to as non-commissioned officers (NCOs). They are recruits, some of whom have acquired relative seniority by being promoted through the enlisted ranks.

Other uniformed organisations, police and some religious groups for example, generally follow a similar system of referring to senior staff as officers.

Most commercial companies prefer to refer to their employees as staff or personnel with levels of management that lead up to a board of directors.

In the case of Google you can safely refer to either staff or personnel although they are said to refer to themselves as Googlers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-commissioned_officer 
http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/staff%20personnel
http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2007-11-28-n25.html